# invalid ID error using SOQL to get field from related record

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, salesforce-id

I am getting an *invalid ID* error in my VF page on the below code and I don't understand what I am missing.

In my controller's constructor I am running the below code:

```
system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE demand ID: '+sObjectRFC.Demand__c);

system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE GET DEMAND QRY');
if (sObjectRFC.Status__c=='Converted' && sObjectRFC.Demand__c !=''){
    system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE GET DEMAND inside IF block');
    demandName=[Select Id, Name from apm2__Demand__c where Id =: sObjectRFC.Demand__c].Name;
    system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE demand ID: '+sObjectRFC.Demand__c);

    //demandName='TEST DEMAND';
}
```

in the developer console logs I can see that `sObjectRFC.Demand__c` = 'a0U8E000002tZwj'

and I can access that record on the Demand object through salesforce with the url `https://domain.salesforce.com/a0U8E000002tZwj`

Of course I can show the Id in my VF page with no problems, but I want to show the record identifier which looks like this: `D-04235`

In the Demand object, the field is defined as:

[image]

Now, in the developer console I can write the below SOQL query:

> Select Name, Id from apm2__Demand__c where Id ='a0U8E000002tZwj'

and it returns a record with the results as below:
[image]

In my VF page, I want to show the *Name* field from the demand object, which should be **D-04235**

but the when I run my VF page, all I can see in the log (developer console) is:

[image]

so it just stops with that error after the line `system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE GET DEMAND QRY');`

so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check the status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Id fields cannot be compared with the '' value. If you need to check for blank , then use "null" instead of ''.
So change your check like this :

```
system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE demand ID: '+sObjectRFC.Demand__c);

system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE GET DEMAND QRY');
if (sObjectRFC.Status__c=='Converted' && sObjectRFC.Demand__c != null){
    system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE GET DEMAND inside IF block');
    demandName=[Select Id, Name from apm2__Demand__c where Id =: sObjectRFC.Demand__c].Name;
    system.debug('SystemChangeRequest View/Edit PAGE demand ID: '+sObjectRFC.Demand__c);

    //demandName='TEST DEMAND';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it, such an unhelpful error message from SalesForce as usual :)

Comment: no worries, yeah what to say  :)